# Android HCE protocol - need help to emulate card

Tags: java, android, nfc, hce

I have been trying to implement Android HCE protocol and have gone through all the available documents on the subject. However, I am unable to find any relevant code that can help me with my project. I have searched the whole web, but all the available code is outdated. Do I need specific code to communicate with my HCE app or it can be emulated to any NFC reader?

This is my HCE code:

```
public class MyHostApduService extends HostApduService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyHostApduService";
    private static final String MY_UID = "F00000000A0101";
    private static final String RESPONSE_SUCCESS = "good";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG, "Service started");
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] commandApdu, Bundle extras) {
        String hexCommandApdu = bytesToHex(commandApdu);
        if (hexCommandApdu.startsWith(MY_UID)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Received command: " + hexCommandApdu);
            return RESPONSE_SUCCESS.getBytes();
        }
        return new byte[]{(byte) 0x6A, (byte) 0x81};
    }

    @Override
    public void onDeactivated(int reason) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Service deactivated");
    }

    private String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte aByte : bytes) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", aByte));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

got nothing in response.

I followed this project https://github.com/championswimmer/NFC-host-card-emulation-Android/tree/master/CardEmulation but it doesn't work...

I am looking for sample code that can help me emulate a card, and when another device reads that card, it should see the string that I have emulated. I would really appreciate it if someone could provide me with the necessary code to achieve this.

Thank you in advance for your help!

**EDITED**

Manifest file:

```
<!-- Card emulation was introduced in API 19. -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc.hce" android:required="true" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.HceTestApp"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service android:name=".MyHostApduService"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NFC_SERVICE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.action.HOST_APDU_SERVICE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="android.nfc.cardemulation.host_apdu_service"
            android:resource="@xml/apduservice" />
    </service>

</application>
```

ApduService:

```
<host-apdu-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:requireDeviceUnlock="false">
<aid-group
    android:category="other">
    <aid-filter android:name="F00000000A0101"/>
</aid-group>
```

Edit:  I apologize for the confusion in my original post. To clarify, I am only looking to emulate a string to an NFC reader. I would like to know if it's possible to do so without emulating a specific type of card. My use case is simple, and I only require the basic functionality of emulating a string via NFC and presenting it to the reader. Thank you for any advice or information you can provide.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to your response i used one of that links that you gave me.
Link: https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid

And i successfully get to point that hce protocol works and gives me this output:

```
2023-04-03 17:57:42.465 5014-5014/? D/HostEmulationManager: Binding to service ComponentInfo{com.softing.kthcapp/com.softing.ktprojhc.cardEmulation.KHostApduService} for userid:0
2023-04-03 17:57:42.689 5014-7178/? D/HostEmulationManager: Binding to service ComponentInfo{com.softing.kthcapp/com.softing.ktprojhc.cardEmulation.KHostApduService} for userid:0
2023-04-03 17:57:42.703 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: 00A4040007D276000085010100
2023-04-03 17:57:42.703 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: APDU_SELECT triggered. Our Response: 9000
2023-04-03 17:57:42.724 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: 00A4000C02E103
2023-04-03 17:57:42.724 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: CAPABILITY_CONTAINER_OK triggered. Our Response: 9000
2023-04-03 17:57:42.742 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: processCommandApdu() | incoming commandApdu: 00B000000F
2023-04-03 17:57:42.742 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: READ_CAPABILITY_CONTAINER triggered. Our Response: 001120FFFFFFFF0406E104FFFE00FF9000
2023-04-03 17:57:42.757 18403-18403/com.softing.kthcapp I/HostApduService: onDeactivated() Fired! Reason: 0
2023-04-03 17:57:42.757 5014-7178/? D/HostEmulationManager: Unbinding from service ComponentInfo{com.softing.kthcapp/com.softing.ktprojhc.cardEmulation.KHostApduService}
2023-04-03 17:58:46.646 3025-3175/? W/ActivityManager: Stopping service due to app idle: u0a508 -2m24s442ms com.softing.kthcapp/com.softing.ktprojhc.cardEmulation.KHostApduService
```

So I now know that HCE protocol works, and problem is NFC reader. From same library copied nfc reader but he doesn't work.
Code:

```
    import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE
import android.content.Intent
import android.nfc.NdefMessage
import android.nfc.NfcAdapter
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import com.softing.kthcred.parser.NdefMessageParser
import kotlin.math.log


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var mNfcAdapter: NfcAdapter? = null
    private var mPendingIntent: PendingIntent? = null
    private lateinit var mTvView: TextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        initView()
        mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this)

        if (checkNFCEnable()) {
            mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this, 0,
                Intent(this, this.javaClass)
                    .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), FLAG_MUTABLE
            )
        } else {
            mTvView.text = getString(R.string.tv_noNfc)
        }

    }


    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mNfcAdapter?.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, null, null)
    }


    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mNfcAdapter?.disableForegroundDispatch(this)
    }


    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED == intent.action) {
            intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES)?.also { rawMessages ->
                val messages: List<NdefMessage> = rawMessages.map { it as NdefMessage }
                // Process the messages array.
                Log.i("STATUSSS", "onNewIntent: "+rawMessages)
                parserNDEFMessage(messages)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun parserNDEFMessage(messages: List<NdefMessage>) {
        val builder = StringBuilder()
        val records = NdefMessageParser.parse(messages[0])
        val size = records.size

        for (i in 0 until size) {
            val record = records.get(i)
            val str = record.str()
            builder.append(str).append("\n")
        }
        mTvView.text = builder.toString()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        mTvView = findViewById<View>(R.id.nfc_activity_tv_info) as TextView
    }

    private fun checkNFCEnable(): Boolean {
        return if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
            mTvView.text = getString(R.string.tv_noNfc)
            false
        } else {
            mNfcAdapter!!.isEnabled
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: You are talking about "cards" - do you mean payment cards like a credit card or a card that has an NFC-chip embedded (like a NTAG21x or Mifare Ultralight) ? For a very limited overview: to get a card read by an NFC reader the reader must know what type of card is presented to him. A payment terminal e.g. knows that a e.g. VisaCard is tapped to him. There is a "general type" and that is a card holding  "NDEF" formatted data - in that case the reader asks for a special application identifier (AID) to get access to this card. So please edit your question and give us some more information, thanks.

Comment: Second: please edit the post and show us your AndroidManifest.xml and /res/xml/apduservice.xml contents, thanks.

Comment: This https://github.com/underwindfall/NFCAndroid does work for Ndef data for me on Android 10

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for clarification and giving more data to us.

Regarding your use case "emulate a string to an NFC reader": you do have two choices:

a) **transfer only the string**: for this you need a specific app that is running on NFC reader side to decode the data. If the NFC reader is an IOS device you will not get the data as Apple does not allow to get the "raw" data from the NFC reader.

b) **build an NDEF message and emulate a card holding this NDEF message**: that way most of the readers will detect the NDEF message and display it with an app available for the chosen NDEF message type (e.g. if the message type is of "URI" a browser will try to display and "read" the URI/URL. The second way b) is used in the linked repository (see comment from @Andrew).

Comment: I used b) and successfully I got that HCE protocol to work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simulating a card requires system-level signatures. Do you possess system-level signatures, or can you use an Xposed module to hook 'com.android.nfc'? Doing so will make it work.